# Almost sure convergence of smallest eigenvector of diagonal matrix

Tags: random-matrices, limits-and-convergence, eigenvector

I have that a sequence of random matrices, $M_n$, converges almost surely to a diagonal matrix, $D$, with finite real entries on its diagonal. During convergence, the off-diagonals are not necessarily zero. How can I go about showing that the smallest eigenvector of $M_n$ converges almost surely to the smallest eigenvector of $D$?

**Edit:** If it helps, at least one diagonal entry of $D$ is zero and each $M_n$ is symmetric.

Comment: You need to make some assumptions  on the nature of *randomness* of the matrices $M_n$  that I gather  are finite dimensional. If you assume that the entries of $M_n$   are continuous random variables  then the result  is true because in this case, with probability one,  the spectrum of $M_n$ is simple.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu "because in this case, with probability one, the spectrum of $M_n$ is simple."  Can you elaborate on why this implies the result?

Comment: I think the idea is that if the spectrum is simple, then the eigenvectors and eigenvalues vary continuously. Hence if the limiting diagonal matrix has almost surely got distinct eigenvalues, then the eigenspaces of the limiting matrix are one-dimensional and are spanned by elements of the standard basis. By continuity, this is also true for nearby matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of symmetric matrices that have multiple eigenvalues has Lebesgue measure 0. If the probability measure you use on the space of  matrices is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, then  the probability that a  random matrix has multiple eigenvalues is zero.  I assume that this is the case.  Assume that the matrices are $d\times d$.

$\newcommand{\bP}{\mathbb{P}}$ $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $\newcommand{\eO}{\mathscr{O}}$  Suppose that your random matrices are defined on the probability space $(\Omega,\eO,\bP)$.  Let $N\in\eO$ such that $\bP[N]=0$ and for any $\omega\in\Omega\setminus N$  all the matrices $M_n(\omega)$  have simple eigenvalues and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} M_n(\omega)=D. $$

Denote by $\lambda_1(\omega)$  the smallest eigenvalue of $M_n(\omega)$ and by $\phi_n(\omega)$ an eigenvector of Euclidean norm $1$ corresponding to this eigenvalue. (There are two choices for $\phi_n(\omega)$ since $\lambda_1(\omega)$ is simple.) Then for any $\phi\in\bR^d$ of Euclidean  norm $1$ we have

$$ \lambda_1(\omega)=\langle\; M_n(\omega)\phi_n(\omega),\phi_n(\omega)\;\rangle\leq \langle\; M_n(\omega)\phi,\phi\;\rangle.  $$

If we let $n\to \infty$ along a subsequence $n_k$ such that $\phi_{n_k}(\omega)$ converges to some $\phi_\infty(\omega)$ of norm $1$ we deduce

$$ \langle\; D\phi_\infty(\omega),\phi_\infty(\omega)\;\rangle \leq \langle\; D\phi,\phi\; \rangle,\;\;\forall \phi\in\bR^d,\;\;\Vert\phi\Vert=1. $$

This proves that  any limit vector $\phi_\infty(\omega)$ of the sequence $(\; \phi_n(\omega)\;)$ is an eigenvector of norm $1$ of $D$ corresponding to the lowest eigenvalue.  That is the best that you can hope.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have a follow-up question: In your proof, you used the fact that $M_n$ has distinct eigenvalues with probability $1$. We do not need to assume this for the limiting matrix $D$ right? For example, a sequence of Wishart matrices with $n$ degrees of freedom converges to identity, but the proof would hold (and we can show that the smallest eigenvalue converges to $1$), right?